# Scrapy : calling different function for different URL

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, callback, scrapy, response

I am new to scrapy. I am trying to get response for different page which have different design.

> I extracted name of link and address of link. And from that i combined
>   the extracted address with the raw link which is desired for the to be
>   visited web page.
>
> My code:

import scrapy

```
class JobCategorySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'job_category'
    allowed_domains = ['www.jobspider.com/job/',
                       'www.jobspider.com/job/browse-resumes.asp',
                       'www.jobspider.com/job/resume-search-results.asp/']

    start_urls = ['http://www.jobspider.com/job/browse-resumes.asp']

    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//*[@face="Arial"]/a')
        raw_url = unicode('http://www.jobspider.com/job/')
        data = {}
        for entry in table:
            name = entry.xpath('.//text()').extract()
            address = entry.xpath('.//@href').extract()
            data[name[0]] = address[0]

        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            if key == "Human Resources":
                category_url = raw_url+value
                print category_url
                #print type(category_url)
                # Request(url=category_url, callback=self.Hr, meta={'data': data})

                yield scrapy.Request(category_url,callback = self.Hr(data=data) )

    def Hr(self, response, data):
        print response
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @gangabass code is not doing its purpose

Comment: @gangabass headline of the problem is code's purpose

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you are trying to have different callbacks (pipelines).

What you can do is override `start_requests` and call to a different callback per link classification.

For example, see the code below. I override the start_requests and I can loop over `start_urls`. According to some logic I can set a different callback.

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request

class JobCategorySpider(Spider):
    name = 'job_category'
    allowed_domains = ['www.jobspider.com/job/',
                       'www.jobspider.com/job/browse-resumes.asp',
                       'www.jobspider.com/job/resume-search-results.asp/']

    start_urls = ['http://www.jobspider.com/job/browse-resumes.asp']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            if url == "http://www.jobspider.com/job/browse-resumes.asp":
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_hr)
            else:
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_developer)

    def parse_hr(self, response):
        ....

    def parse_developer(self, response):
        ....
```